# Grails relationship not saving

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following setup:

```
class Parent {

    static hasMany = [ children: String ]

}


class ParentController {

    def create() {
        Parent entry = params.id ? Parent.load(params.id as long) : new Parent()

        entry.properties = params
        if (request.method == "POST") {         
            if (entry.validate()) {

                entry.save()
                assert !entry.hasErrors()

                println entry.children // prints [two, one]

                println Parent.load(entry.id).children // prints []
                redirect(action:'index')
                return
            }
        }
        return [
            entry: entry,
            entities: ["one","two"]
        ]

    }

}
```

Why are the children not saving along with the parent?

(I also tried making the children another domain object, however that made no difference)

Comment: Load normally is used when you want only the id to search in relationships. Changing to `get()` helps?

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but get() makes no difference (I'm actually doing a list() at another point in the application which also has no children, I added the line above to debug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure exactly what solved my problem, changing the `save()` to `save(flush: true)` allowed me to see the exception that Hibernate was throwing.